# Find the orthogonal matrix such $A\alpha =\beta$

Tags: matrices

Give the two martices 
$$\alpha=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
3\\
4
\end{bmatrix},\beta=\begin{bmatrix}
5\\
0\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}$$
find a orthogonal matrix $A$ such 
$$A\alpha =\beta$$

Answer (score 1):

We will take $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$ by two rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**First Rotation:**

We will rotate the vector in the $yz$-plane such that the $y$ coordinate of the new vector is $0$, i.e. 
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & \cos\theta_1 & -\sin\theta_1 \\
0 & \sin\theta_1 & \cos\theta_1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
3 \\
4\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
5\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
for some $\theta_1$.

**Second Rotation:**

We will rotate in the $xz$-plane, i.e.
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
5\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
5 \\
0 \\
-1\\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Hence the desired orthogonal matrix $A$ is given by
\begin{align}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & \cos\theta_1 & -\sin\theta_1 \\
0 & \sin\theta_1 & \cos\theta_1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sin\theta_1 & \cos\theta_1\\
0 & \cos\theta_1 & -\sin\theta_1\\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Note the angle $\theta_1$ is relative to the $3, 4, 5$ right triangle.